# How to make tex4ht output a title

Tags: tex4ht

Compiling with htlatex the following small2e.tex

```
\documentclass{article}        % Your input file must contain these two lines 
\begin{document}               % plus the \end{document} command at the end.

\section{Simple Text}          % This command makes a section title.

Words are separated by one or more spaces.  Paragraphs are separated by
one or more blank lines.
\end{document}
```

Creates a nice html file but with an empty title (it contains `<title></title>`).
Is there a way to force tex4ht to output a title?

Using the following line in a private configuration file:

```
\HCode{<title>} My title \HCode{</title>}
```

simply adds "My title" as a title, but does not substitute the empty one, thus creating validation problems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case that you don't want a printed title: You can use in the private .cfg (needs naturally a `\title` command in the document):

```
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\Configure{TITLE+}{\@title}      
\makeatother
```

In your document you can also use

```
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\Tag{TITLE+}{\@title}
```

Comment: Thanks, @Ulrike! It looks as though one can just put `\Tag{TITLE+}{My title}` after the `\begin{document}` and dispense with `\title` and `\makeatletter` if there is no other use for `\title`

Answer (score 6):

`tex4ht` works in the same way as ordinary LaTeX with regard to titles.  You *declare* your title with the `\title{My Amazing Document}` and then *use* it with the command `\maketitle`.  You can also define `\author{Me}` and `\date{\today}` (note that the *use* command is just a single invocation of `\maketitle`).

```
\documentclass{article}

\title{Sample Document}
\author{Me, Myself, and I}
\date{\today}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Simple Text}

Words are separated by one or more spaces.
Paragraphs are separated by one or more blank lines.
\end{document}
```

The above results in a correct `<title>Sample Document</title>` in the head of resulting HTML document.